# Jupyter Notebook Out of PTY Devices Error

Tags: python, jupyter, pty

I am running Python 3.6.3, CentOS 7.4.1708 and notebook 5.2.1. When I type `!pwd` or `!ls` within a Jupyter Notebook, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-8d5fad910f3e> in <module>()
----> 1 get_ipython().system('pwd')

...

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/pty.py in _open_terminal()
     57                 continue
     58             return (fd, '/dev/tty' + x + y)
---> 59     raise OSError('out of pty devices')
     60 
     61 def slave_open(tty_name):

OSError: out of pty devices
```

I've tried increasing my kernel.pty.max which did not help. I've also successfully run `!pwd` and `!ls` within iPython without same issue. What could be causing this error?